# For the same ID in one column, how do I write a CASE statement for the future dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, case, partition-by

For the following table, I want to write a CASE statement: For the same ID, if more than one Dates are in the future and Renew = "Yes," fill out the Action column with "Needs Review". I assume OVER(PARTITION BY() is supposed to be used, but not sure how

Original Table:

| ID | Date | Renew |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 06-01-2023 | Yes |
| 123 | 06-01-2022 | Yes |
| 123 | 06-01-2021 | Yes |

Expected Outcome (with the CASE statement):

| ID | Date | Renew | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 06-01-2023 | Yes | Needs Review |
| 123 | 06-01-2022 | Yes | Needs Review |
| 123 | 06-01-2021 | Yes | Needs Review |

Comment: tag question with database platform

Comment: If past and future dates are to give "needs review" please explain the logic

Comment: case **expression**, not: case *statement*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a conditional SUM() to count the number of rows marked "Renew", with future dates. Then return "Needs Review" if the count is > 1.

You didn't specify your dbms, but try

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT t.*
       , IF(t.NumToReview > 1, 'Needs Review', NULL) AS [Action]
FROM (
       SELECT 
          Id
         , [Date]
         , [Renew]
         , SUM( CASE WHEN Date > cast(getDate() as date) 
                       AND Renew = 'Yes' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END
         ) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) AS NumToReview
      FROM  YourTable     
  ) t
```

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT t.*
       , IF(t.NumToReview > 1, 'Needs Review', NULL) AS Action
FROM (
       SELECT 
          Id
         , `Date`
         , Renew
         , SUM( CASE WHEN `Date` > CAST(now() AS DATE) 
                       AND Renew = 'Yes' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END
         ) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) AS NumToReview
      FROM  YourTable  
  ) t
```

**Results:**

| Id | Date | Renew | NumToReview | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 06-01-2023 | Yes | 2 | Needs Review |
| 123 | 06-01-2022 | Yes | 2 | Needs Review |
| 123 | 06-01-2021 | Yes | 2 | Needs Review |